# SEO: Getting site to show in location-specific searches

Tags: seo, geolocation

I'm really new to this SEO world and I've been reading a lot to try and figure it out.

We have a site that allows users to browse/create events anywhere. And we fill it with content from the main cities in the US.

We would like it to show for searches for things like "events in san francisco" or "what to do in new york", however, since the site is not really location-specific, I'm not really sure where to begin.

I've been thinking a couple of things, maybe you can help me decide if these would be a good way to start or if I should try something different.

1- Allow something like location-specific urls (e.g. example.com/browse/san-francisco) could just show the main page centered in San Francisco.

2- Change the headers/title of the page so it adapts automatically to the city being browsed (and change this dynamically as the user changes the location of the map).

3- Add internal links to different locations (e.g. add a link at the footer of the page that says "Events in Seattle" that makes the site load events in that city. (this would probably depend on implementing #1).

What do you guys think? will any of these really help or should I look for a different approach? any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your three approaches can be implemented at the same time.

I'm not sure the dynamic change of page title would help from an SEO perspective (point 2), but it would still be a nice feature for your users.

The third point can be extended whenever possible for specific events, like "Finding other Language and cultural exchange in San Francisco", and "Finding other Language and cultural exchange in California".

You could also generate microdata for each event, using the Event representation (see http://schema.org/Event).

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in right direction. There should be one main page for optimized for each city showing that citi's events and in the bottom you can show nearest cities linking to their pages.

Make it US target site in Google Analytics. Also Google is smart enough to correlate words "events in .." or "what to do ..". That is, creating and optimizing single page will do unless you have different information to be separated in another page. So I'd agree with 1,2,3.